# hiding the __proto__ property in Chrome's console

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, console

Whenever I type `console.log/console.dir` on an object, one of the properties that always shows up is `__proto__` which is the constructor.

is there any way to hide this?

Comment: `__proto__` is the constructor? I hardly can believe that.

Comment: You don't want to hide it, what's in the prototype is as important as other properties!

Comment: @Bergi it contains just the constructor, in my case.

Comment: @Pioul In my case it's a custom object and I do

Comment: @qwertymk `.__proto__` is a reference to the object's prototype, not its constructor.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I realize that, see my first comment

Comment: @qwertymk In your first comment you say it refers to the constructor, but I'm telling you that it refers to the prototype, not the constructor.

Comment: If you dont want to inspect the whole object, don't log it but only the things that interest you.

Comment: [It can be done but it's not worth it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52946275/1442225)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redefine console.log:

```
console.log = function (arg) {
    var tempObj;

    if (typeof arg === 'object' && !arg.length) {
        tempObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg));
        tempObj.__proto__ = null;
        return tempObj;
    }

    return arg;
};
```

This won't modify the original object which definitely needs to have __proto__.

Comment: I thought it would show a `null` entry, but somehow `__proto__` diminishes when setting it to `null`.

Comment: This will have limited use. Non-JSON-friendly values won't be displayed.

Comment: I tried it, but the console doesn't show anyting anymore now :S

Answer (score 5):

```
console.debug = function() {
  function clear(o) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
    // [!] clone

    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        obj.__proto__ = null;
        // clear

        for (var j in obj) {
          obj[j] = clear(obj[j]); // recursive
        }
    }
    return obj;
  }
  for (var i = 0, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); i < args.length; i++) {
    args[i] = clear(args[i]);
  }
  console.log.apply(console, args);
};
```

---

```
var mixed = [1, [2, 3, 4], {'a': [5, {'b': 6, c: '7'}]}, [null], null, NaN, Infinity];
console.debug(mixed);
```

Comment: Works like a charm - Thank you : )

Comment: And (as far as I can test..) doesn't remove the prototypes from the actual objects - so safe to use : )

Comment: I take it back !!!! dont do this !!!! it does mess with the object - just spent an entire day fighting with select2 - in desperation switched from console.debug to console.log - All my troubles went away : )

Answer (score 1):

Use Opera and [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/). In its settings (script tab), you can uncheck the option "Show Prototypes".

Comment: This may be correct but the question is tagged as Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.create(null)` to create objects without `__proto__`

If you just want to hide the proto showing up on objects that have `.__proto__` in console, you can't. Though I don't see why you would want to.

Btw, `.__proto__` is not the object's constructor but its [[[Prototype]] link](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2).

Comment: If I may digress, for `var o = {};`, why is `o.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') //false`, but `'__proto__' in o // true`?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I don't know, it's not like it's not non-standard, deprecated and fragile feature. It returns `true` in safari, `false` in firefox, chrome and opera.

Comment: @Esailija: Opera does not support that property at all, so `true` would be very unlikely :-)

Comment: @Bergi lol I have 9.80 (I know, rite) and it does support it, returns `false` though :P

Comment: @Esailija Ah yes, that's the reason. It's not a native ECMAScript property, as it doesn't conform to the language's rules for properties.

Answer (score 0):

Although `.__proto__` is important, there is obviously a way to hide things from the console. This is demonstrated when you try to do:

```
 for (var i in function.prototype) {
    console.log(i+": "+function.prototype[i].toString())
    }
```

There'll be some things that aren't logged to the console, and I think that is exactly what this whole topic is about (IMO answers should allow all prototypes so anybody visiting this topic can use it).

Also: The [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is not the constructor. It is the object's highest priority prototype object. It is important that you don't delete the proto and leave it alone because if there is a method there that JavaScript relies on then the whole thing goes to shit. For the constructor look at [`obj.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor), it doesn't screw with the whole damn thing and it may just be what it is named, the constructor, imagine that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hiding the `__proto__` is not worth it!** *(see below why)*

```
var old_log = console.log;
console.log = function ()
{
    function clearProto(obj)
    {
        if (obj && typeof(obj) === "object")
        {
            var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
            temp.__proto__ = null;
            for (var prop in temp)
                temp[prop] = clearProto(temp[prop]);
            return temp;
        }
        return obj;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
        arguments[i] = clearProto(arguments[i]);
    old_log.apply(console, arguments);
}

var mixed = [1, [2, 3, 4], {'a': [5, {'b': 6, c: {'d': '7'}}]}, [null], null, NaN, Infinity];
console.log([1, 2, 3], mixed);
old_log([1, 2, 3], mixed); // 4 comparison (original mixed has __proto__)
```

`NaN` and `Infinity` can't be cloned with JSON. In Chrome you also get the line-number on the right side of the dev tools. By overriding `console.log` you'll lose that. Not worth to hide `__proto__` over that one!