# JavaScript debugging - hiding class methods in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, webstorm

JavaScript debugging in the IDE (VSCode or WebStorm) can become difficult if you try to debug instances of a class that defines many methods:

[image]

As you can see each `Vector` has about 15 methods. I am interested to see only the instance attributes (`x`, `y`, and so on) and to hide the methods while debugging. The methods are the same for each instance and are not relevant. This makes debugging difficult: this may seem like a small issue but if you need to debug a long session of 'big' instances you can get lost.

Is there a way (via the IDE, or via another setting), to filter instances methods on the IDE debugger?

If I could do this I could see `x`, `y` values inline and that could save me tone of time, currently, the inline preview in the IDE is overwhelmed with the irrelevant functions signatures.

#### Alternative:

Is there a way to edit the built-in preview function of the debugger?
I could overwrite `console.log` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30085019/10577976) but it won't effect the IDE preview:

```js
const tempConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = (...argss) => {
  function clear(o) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
    // [!] clone

    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
      obj.__proto__ = null;
      // clear

      for (var j in obj) {
        obj[j] = clear(obj[j]); // recursive
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }
  for (var i = 0, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(argss, 0); i < args.length; i++) {
    args[i] = clear(args[i]);
  }
  tempConsoleLog.apply(console, args);
};
```

No effect on debugger preview:
[image]

Works great when invoking `console.log(...args)`:
[image]

I still looking for a way to hack the IDE preview somehow...

Edit:

Vector class:

```js
export class Vector {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  faceDirs: Dir[]; // all allowed dirs
  _chosenFaceDir: Dir; // chosen dir
  dir: Dir;

  constructor(x: number | Vector, y?: number) {
    if (x instanceof Vector) {
      this.x = x.x;
      this.y = x.y;
      if (typeof y === 'number') throw Error('illegal');
    } else {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y as number;
    }
    this.faceDirs = null;
    this._chosenFaceDir = null;

    if (!(this instanceof Dir)) this.dir = new Dir(this.x, this.y);
  }

  // eq = (p: Vector) => p.x === this.x && p.y === this.y;
  eq = (p: Vector) => eq(p.x, this.x) && eq(p.y, this.y);
  notEq = (p: Vector) => !eq(p.x, this.x) || !eq(p.y, this.y);

  add = (p: Vector | number) => operatorFunc(this, p, operators.add);
  sub = (p: Vector | number) => operatorFunc(this, p, operators.sub);
  mul = (p: Vector | number) => operatorFunc(this, p, operators.mul);
  dev = (p: Vector | number) => operatorFunc(this, p, operators.dev);

  absSize = () => Math.sqrt(this.x ** 2 + this.y ** 2);
  size = () => this.x + this.y;
  abs = () => new Vector(Math.abs(this.x), Math.abs(this.y));
```

Comment: WebStorm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24515, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27621 and linked tickets I guess. **P.S.** I do not see why `console.log()` should affect the debugger at all: `console.log` does not report anything to the actual JS debugger; the debugger queries the actual "execution environment" about what variables it has etc.

Comment: "*The methods are the same for each instance and are not relevant.*" - then your class should define them in the prototype, and not assign separate functions to each instance. What your debugger is telling is that they *are* instance attributes, exactly like `x` and `y` (except for holding function objects not numbers). They're probably even created before them in the constructor, as the debugger keeps the creation order. Please show us your `class Vector` declaration.

Comment: @Bergi i added the Vector class, how should I define the methods in the proto?

Comment: @EliavLouski Arrow functions are created on the instance.

Comment: @EliavLouski Use proper method definitions, not [arrow functions in class fields](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1).

Comment: if i will use the `function` keyword it will still be on instance.
do I have to define all these methods outside the `class` scope like `Vector.prototype.add = ...` or there is a syntax for define functions on the prototype within the class body?

Comment: thank you @Bergi
well it solves my problem for me for this case. you can write it as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods show up on the instance in the debugger because they *are* properties on the instance itself. Your `class` declaration uses class fields, which create instance properties as if they were property assignments in the constructor. [Don't do that](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1), it's inefficient and unnecessary in your case, and has weird effects such as the one you're experiencing.

Instead, use normal [method definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#prototype_methods):

```
export class Vector {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  faceDirs: Dir[]; // all allowed dirs
  _chosenFaceDir: Dir; // chosen dir
  dir: Dir;

  constructor(x: number | Vector, y?: number) {
    if (x instanceof Vector) {
      this.x = x.x;
      this.y = x.y;
      if (typeof y === 'number') throw Error('illegal');
    } else {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y as number;
    }
    this.faceDirs = null;
    this._chosenFaceDir = null;

    if (!(this instanceof Dir)) this.dir = new Dir(this.x, this.y);
  }

  eq(p: Vector) { return eq(p.x, this.x) && eq(p.y, this.y); } }
  notEq(p: Vector) { return !eq(p.x, this.x) || !eq(p.y, this.y); }

  add(p: Vector | number) { return operatorFunc(this, p, operators.add); }
  sub(p: Vector | number) { return operatorFunc(this, p, operators.sub); }
  mul(p: Vector | number) { return operatorFunc(this, p, operators.mul); }
  dev(p: Vector | number) { return operatorFunc(this, p, operators.dev); }

  absSize() { return Math.sqrt(this.x ** 2 + this.y ** 2); }
  size() { return this.x + this.y; }
  abs() { return new Vector(Math.abs(this.x), Math.abs(this.y)); }
}
```